# How to use stringstream in Xilinx SDK?

Tags: embedded, xilinx, xilinx-edk

When trying to add

```
#include <sstream>
```

which is needed for stringstream, I get several errors, the following included:

expected ';' at end of input
expected '}' at end of input
macro "str" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given

How to enable using stringstream ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in the Xilinx SDK.

You need to undef a macro named str.

Replace

```
#include <sstream>
```

with

```
#undef str
#include <sstream>
```

Credit:
This method was proposed by sparks333 and can be found here:
https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/Error-with-Standard-Libaries-in-Zynq/td-p/450032

Answer (score 0):

I just signed up just to answer this question.

I went through this post some time ago and used the solution posed, even though I didn't like it very much. It was a mistake.

This solution can cause deadlock of the system after some time in a random way, very difficult to debug.

I propose the following solution:

1. create the file "compatible_sstream.h":

   > ```
   > #pragma push_macro("str")
   > #undef str
   > #include <sstream>
   > #pragma pop_macro("str")
   > ```
2. replace `#include <sstream>` with `#include "compatible_sstream.h"` in
   all the other files.
3. wrap all calls to `std::ostringstream::str` in parentheses as in the example:

   > ```
   > std::ostringstream foo()
   > {
   > // ...
   > }
   > ```

   > ```
   > void main()
   > {
   > // ...
   > std::cout << (foo().str)() << std::endl;
   > // ...
   > }
   > ```

Apologies in advance if I have not followed any of the posting rules correctly.